# Variance of Hypergeometric

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

In Introduction to Probability by Blitzstein and Hwang, #48 of Chapter 4 asks the reader to first find $E \binom{X}{2}$ "*by thinking*" instead of using any "complicated calculations" and then says to use that value to compute $Var(X)$.  Over here $X$ ~ $HG(w, b, n)$.

I found $E \binom{X}{2} = \frac{\binom{w}{2}}{\binom{N}{2}} \cdot \binom{n}{2}$ by "thinking," but that did not yield the variance that they provided as a solution, which is in particular $Var(X) = \frac{N-n}{N-1} npq$ where $N = w + b, p = \frac{w}{N}$ and $q = 1-p$. I found by noting that the probability any two selected items have tag w (I could rigorize this with indicator variables, but since it is very uniform, I'm hoping this is clear enough).

I can't figure out whether my solution is wrong because I computed $E \binom{X}{2}$ wrong or if I made some mistake in my (incredibly painful) computation. As such, I was wondering if someone could confirm that my computation for $E \binom{X}{2}$ is correct.

Comment: You should check if it is correct by noting that $E(\binom{X}{2}) = \frac{1}{2}E(X(X-1)) = \frac{1}{2} [E(X^2) - E(X)] = \frac{1}{2}(\sigma^2 + \mu^2 - \mu)$ where $\sigma^2$ is the variance and $\mu$ is the mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computation of $\mathbb E[\binom {\mathbf X}2]$ is correct. From it, we get $\mathbb E[\mathbf X(\mathbf X-1)] = \frac{w(w-1) \cdot n(n-1)}{N(N-1)}$. To get $\text{Var}[\mathbf X] = \mathbb E[\mathbf X^2] - \mathbb E[\mathbf X]^2$, we should add $\mathbb E[\mathbf X] = \frac{ w n}{N}$ and subtract $\mathbb E[\mathbf X]^2 = \frac{w^2 n^2}{N^2}$.

To simplify the algebra, note that all three of these terms have a factor of $\frac{wn}{N} = np$ in them, which we also want in the final answer. This leaves us with
$$
   \text{Var}[\mathbf X] = \frac{wn}{N} \left(\frac{(w-1)(n-1)}{N-1} + 1 - \frac{w n}{N}\right).
$$
Combining all three terms inside the parentheses is the painful part, but it should give $\frac{N^2 - Nn - Nw + nw}{N(N-1)}$ after some terms cancel, which factors as $\frac{(N-n)(N-w)}{N(N-1)}$.

Now, we get
$$
   \text{Var}[\mathbf X] = \frac{N-n}{N-1} \cdot n \cdot \frac wN \cdot \frac{N-w}{n} = \frac{N-n}{N-1} npq.
$$

Comment: Thanks for verifying my computation and strategy! Still haven't found the computation error, but its good to know that all of my conceptual work was correct.